# highlighted query has hits but misses highlighted fragments (for some documents)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am facing very awkward results when I try to query a highlight 
search to Elastic Search 2.4. I query for a term which contains hyphen('-') for eg Drug-related and i get a result set, the response are generally all correct, but some result's fragments are like

**Result:**
1) other costs of drug abuse include drug-related deaths,  cocaine, crack, and methamphetamines.
2) Drug-related crimes are,  drug-related wealth, Escobar financed a private army to conduct,
3) in was inadvertently driven into the middle of a Drug
4) -related shootout between traffickers at the international airport

problem : the text (Drug-Related) has broken into 2 fragments (3 & 4).
expected : drug-related should come as single line.

Here is my query

```
 {"size" : 5000,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [ {
        "match" : {
          "bookId" : {
            "query" : "<SomeID>",
            "type" : "boolean",
            "operator" : "AND"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "match" : {
          "contentType" : {
            "query" : "booktext",
            "type" : "boolean",
            "operator" : "AND"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "match" : {
              "content" : {
                "query" : "drug-related*",
                "type" : "phrase_prefix"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } ]
    }
  },
  "highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : [ "" ],
    "post_tags" : [ "" ],
    "fragment_size" : 60,
    "number_of_fragments" : 5000,
    "boundary_max_scan" : 10,
    "highlight_query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ {
          "match" : {
            "bookId" : {
              "query" : "<BookID>",
              "type" : "boolean",
              "operator" : "AND"
            }
          }
        }, {
          "match" : {
            "contentType" : {
              "query" : "booktext",
              "type" : "boolean",
              "operator" : "AND"
            }
          }
        }, {
          "bool" : {
            "must" : {
              "match" : {
                "content" : {
                  "query" : "drug-related*",
                  "type" : "phrase_prefix"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } ]
      }
    },
    "fields" : {
      "content" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

Query Response : ** I cannot paste full content here but I am adding response hits

```
   {content=[content], fragments[[ accurate figures available regarding the cost of drug-related prostitution,  mentioned, other costs of drug abuse include drug-related deaths,  cocaine, crack, and methamphetamines.

Drug-related crimes are,  drug-related wealth, Escobar financed a private army to conduct,  believed to be drug related. According to a news story on this, ,” the President wrote. “We have him.” (Bio. 2016)
Drug-related violence,  in was inadvertently driven into the middle of a Drug, -related shootout between traffickers at the international airport]]}
```

I just don't see a pattern here. Can anyone please explain the reason for that ?

Comment: Can you add the response you're getting from elastic?

Comment: Hi @aclokay, I could not update the complete response as the text is huge but I've added response hits above.

Comment: Maybe it's fragmented because there's a hyphen in the text?

Comment: @aclokay may be, is there any other way I could have them in proper format ?